# wrap_content on recycleview, take height of item (horizontal list)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a RecycleView, set to horizontal. Now i would like the height to match the height of an item in the view. I don't know the height in advance.

Currently i have this:

**Main fragment:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/my_listview"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

**The image**

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/banner_image"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray"
    />
```

but it always takes up the entire screen. so i have a lot of whitespace in between. Is there a way that i could use wrap_content on the recycleview items?

This is what it currently looks like:
[image]

I have placed 2 banners currently, the top one with the big whitespace and small image is the one with the recyclerview. The one below is just the image placed in an imageview (is what it should look like, but i want it with a recyclerview so i can scroll through the banners if i have multiple)

Comment: you've defined your recyclerView with height="match_parent". What happens when you replace that with "wrap_content"?

Comment: Then it takes on the incorrect height, the banner measure about 60px in height but with wrap_content it would resize it to about 30 or something.

Comment: What happens if you define your recyclerView with height as `wrap_content` and remove the `scaleType` and the `adjustViewBounds` from the `ImageView`?

Comment: I have done that now, it stays the same. I updated my original post with an image of what it looks like

Answer (score 1):

> Now i would like the height to match the height of an item in the
>   view. I don't know the height in advance.

During layout pass, `LinearLayoutManager` cannot predict the height of all the views down in the adapter that are yet to be created, ahead of time.

You can `measure()` an item view, probably the first one, from the adapter and then set the height of `RecycleView` through code.

If all items can have different height then you'll have to measure them all, which is certainly not the correct way for a good UI.

Comment: The images all have the same dimensions

Answer (score 0):

You are probably inflating the layout incorrectly.

Did you use?

```
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
```

Try using instead. (The other way messes with measuring)

```
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);
```

Comment: I am currently using the following code to inflate it: `View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.banner_item, parent, false);`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you have the `RecycleView` wrapped inside a `RelativeLayout` ?
I would try to move the `RecycleView` out of the `RelativeLayout` first.

Secondly i see that your `ViewPager` has a `layout_weight` but i do not see a `android:weightSum` attribute in the parent layout. Is there a reason you are specifying the `ViewPager` to have a `weight` but not the `RecycleView` ? Have you tried fixing the size of the `RecyleView` to some dp to check if the arrangement is correct and the `ViewPager` is using the `weight` attribute correctly ?

Thirdly i would try to play around with the `Imageview`. Try maybe wrapping it inside a `RelativeLayout` maybe ? You will have to play around with the parameters there and see if it works out for you. Because you want something custom there is not a straight answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, none of your suggestions seemed to work. when setting it to a fixed dp size, the whitespace seems to scale down respectively to the set dp.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and I wanted to view two images in two columns with the same size in RecyclerView and I could solve the problem by using below code. Please try this.

```
// inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView 
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imgViewIcon;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            int colSpan = 2;
            imgViewIcon.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels / colSpan);
            imgViewIcon.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels / colSpan);

        }
    }
```